# How to strip formatting from a known string

Tags: microsoft-word, rtf

We have a bespoke app from a defunct supplier which uses .rtf templates to create letters. The mechanism is that the templates have keywords in pipes that the app then replaces with data from the user(s) automatically to create letters.

Unfortunately 300+ templates were recently updated and we found the templates were broken. It was discovered that deleting the bookmark and retyping the bookmark fixed this issue. Further investigation showed that if you opened the .rtf template in Notepad then while on the screen it looked like "|EXAMPLE|" that in Notepad it read as "|EXAMPLE @@@@@@|" where @@@@@@ is a load of formatting code I couldn't comprehend. Indeed looking closer in word showed the 2nd pipe to be in a different font size. Simply changing the font size doesn't help, you have to retype.

Is there any way to bulk fix these rtf templates and strip out formatting where it appears between two pipes in the displayed text?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

RTF files are ASCII text with text-based formatting codes. So any tool that is capable of doing a suitable search/replace should be able to do this for each file.

To do it for 300 files, you need some software that will do batch search/replace. Do you have any skills in PowerShell? JavaScript? VBScript?

There are also a number of text editors that do batch search/replace such as Notepad++

Comment: It's not always the same formatting between the pipes though so it's not like I can pattern match a single string. No, I'm an SQL Developer primarily.

Comment: I think it very likely you could work out a regular expression, at least one that hits the majority if nothing else. There are plenty of regex UI's that will help. Then you need a regex search/replace tool that does batches. I think Notepad++ might do it but there are plenty of others.